# ssh access with key authentication does not work

Tags: ssh, cygwin, sshd

I'm trying to set a no-password connection throw two servers, the first (A) runs Win server with Cygwin and the second runs Debian Linux.
I followed this guide: http://troy.jdmz.net/rsync/index.html, so:

### 1.DEB server

1.a. created keys:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -f /home/deb-user/cron/deb-rsync-key
```

1.b copied deb-rsync-key.pub on the Win server using scp & authentication

### 2.Win server

2.a entered the Win server using ssh and authentication and moved `deb-rsync-key.pub` in the `.ssh` folder and then copied the content in the `authorized_keys` file, that I created

2.b made sure that `.ssh` folder had `700` permission and `authorized_keys` file `600`.

2.c made sure that `RSAAuthentication` and `PubkeyAuthentication` keys in `/etc/sshd/sshd_config` were both uncommented and `yes`

2.d Tried to set the `AuthorizedKeysFile` as absolute path pointing to the `autorized_keys` file in the user's home folder (changed from `.ssh/autorized_keys` to `/home/win-user/.ssh/autorized_keys`)

2.e restarted sshd server (`net stop sshd`, `net start sshd`)

### 3.Deb server

Trying to access the win server using the key:

```
ssh -i /home/deb-user/cron/deb-rsync-key win-user@win-host
```

all I get is

```
Connection closed by win-host
```

Nothing is logged in DEB: /var/logs/auth.log

Nothing is logged in WIN: /var/logs/sshd.log

Any help will be much appreciated!

**UPDATE:**
adding -v option in ssh command returns this:

```
OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze3, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to win-host [win-host] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/deb-user/cron/deb-rsync-key.pub type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/deb-user/cron/deb-rsync-key.pub-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'win-host' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/deb-host/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/deb-host/cron/deb-rsync-key.pub
Connection closed by win-host
```

**UPDATE2**
win server .ssh folder permissions are as follows:

```
$ ls -la .ssh
total 6
drwx------+ 1 win-user Domain Users   0 Mar 12 10:26 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 win-user Domain Users   0 Mar 12 10:25 ..
-rw-------  1 win-user Domain Users 396 Mar 12 10:26 authorized_keys
-rw-------  1 win-user Domain Users 396 Mar 12 10:24 deb-rsync-key.pub
```

**UPDATE3:**
folder permissions in DEB server are as follows:

```
$ ls -la /home/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 root  root  4096 31 gen 11.19 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root  root  4096 28 gen 11.59 ..
drwx------ 18 deb-user deb-user 4096 12 mar 11.15 deb-user
```

And folder permissions in Win server as follows:

```
$ ls -la /home/
total 8
drwxrwxrwt+ 1 jbogdani root         0 Oct 20  2011 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 jbogdani root         0 Nov  1 00:44 ..
drwx------+ 1 win-user Domain Users 0 Mar 12 10:25 win-user
```

**UPDATE4**
More verbose:

```
$ ssh -vvv -i /home/de-user/cron/deb-rsync-key win-user@win-host
OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze3, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to win-host [win-host] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /home/deb-user/cron/deb-rsync-key.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /home/deb-user/cron/deb-rsync-key type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/deb-user/cron/deb-rsync-key-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze3
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 139/256
debug2: bits set: 528/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host win-host filename /home/deb-user/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host win-host filename /home/deb-user/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 2
debug1: Host 'win-host' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/deb-user/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug2: bits set: 506/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/deb-user/cron/deb-rsync-key (0xb8f465c0)
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/deb-user/cron/deb-rsync-key
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
Connection closed by win-host
```

Comment: Try ssh'ing with the -v argument, for added verbosity

Comment: Updated with verbose result of ssh command

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, the output for "ls -la /home/win-user/.ssh", so we can see if you have the right permissions

Comment: @brian Updated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think the problem is in your authorized_keys, or possibly **that you don't have rsync installed on the server**.

*Check if rsync is installed first, then let's try to solve the problem in steps:*

First, let's get rid for **from=** and **command=**, that way we can see if it can connect using the key at all.

The resulting line in should look like this:

> ssh-dss AAAAB3NzaC1kc3MAAAEBA ..

Then let's see if we can connect  using ssh directly.

> ssh -i [path-to-key] win-user@win-host

If that works, let's add **ip=**, make sure it's the IP of the client connecting.

> ip="[client-ip]" ssh-dss AAAAB3NzaC1kc3MAAAEBA ..

Try to connect again using the ssh command above.

Lastly, let's add our **validate-rsync**.

> ip="[client-ip]",command="/home/remoteuser/cron/validate-rsync" ssh-dss AAAAB3NzaC1kc3MAAAEBA ..

Now, with the use of **/home/remoteuser/cron/validate-rsync**, you won't be able to use ssh directly, as it's the script prevents the default shell (defined in **/etc/passwd**).

validate-rsync is used to prevent all commands except **rsync --server**.
Instead, you should try a simple rsync from client to server.

> touch test && rsync -vv -e "ssh -i path-to-key" test win-user@win-host

**It can also be cygwin-related, please check out this message:**

http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2008-08/msg00155.html.

Comment: Hello, in the tutorial I quoted I've not gone further the steps I described above. Rsync is installed and works correctly using password. I've not added filters (from= or command+) in the authorized_keys files. I can ssh correctly using password, but I get the errors i described if I try to ssh using the key file. It means I'm not able to get `ssh -i [path-to-key] win-user@win-host` work at all. Double checked files and folders permission in Win and Deb servers: everything seems to be OK....

Comment: Please check for details UPDATE3 in my question.

Comment: Check authorized_keys and see if it's valid. Make sure there are no newlines in the middle of the public key (happens easily when you copy-paste between two terminals), and make sure you got the _whole_ public key.

Comment: Public key is identical in both server: same content, no newlines, etc... I just double-checked.....

Comment: Try ssh again, using -vvv for even more verbosity =)

Comment: Thank you for your patience ;) Check UPDATE 4 for more details.

Comment: debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /home/deb-user/cron/deb-rsync-key. Please make sure that's a valid private key. When you generated the keypair you got (for example) id_rsa and id_rsa.pub. The .pub file is the public key, and should be in the authorized_keys at the host, and other file is the private key.

Comment: But it is there... I have the /home/deb-user/cron/deb-rsync-key and I can open it correctly. I'll try to recreate it.... But I've already done this several times already....

Comment: The only think I can think of now is that it's cygwin-related. Check out this message: http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2008-08/msg00155.html. Make sure you run ssh-host-config, and all that.

Comment: @brian Thank you very much! It WAS a cygwin related issue. Following your link I did solve my problem and was able to ssh (and rsync) passwordless!